# How to change the name of my machine

Tags: google-drive

I have two machines that I use to sync specific folders. When browsing on drive.google.com I am unable to tell the difference between 'My Laptop' and 'My Laptop (1)'.

Does anyone know how to change these names?

[image: Screenshot of my drive.google.com]

Answer (score 3):

Like any other folder.

Right-click the folder > Rename ...

Comment: Do you know how long I looked for that? I am not smart .... Thanks ('',)